# How to dynamically loop a JSON file using Thymeleaf in Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a requirement wherein I need to iterate over a List of Maps i.e. List<Map<String, Object>> grab the data from the list, and map it to a JSON file. Now the challenge is that I need to loop the data dynamically in the JSON file. Well, I do know how to map a single set of data to a JSON file using Thymeleaf but I'm not sure how to dynamically loop a JSON file using Thymeleaf.
The following thing is what I'm aware of -

I have a java class with a method that has the following code that will map the data from a HashMap to the JSON file.

```
public JSONObject response(){
   Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
   Context context = new Context();
   String responsePayload = null;
   JSONObject jsonObject = null;
   data.put("name", "Wayne Rooney")
   data.put("profession", "Footballer")
   context.setVariable("data", data);
   responsePayload = templateEngine.process("resource/payload", context);
   jsonObject = new JSONObject(responsePayload);
}
```

This is how the payload.json file looks

```
{
    "name": "[(${data['name']})]",
    "profession": "[(${data['profession']})]"
}
```

So, my code works smoothly when only a single instance of HashMap data is mapped to the JSON file, but my next requirement is how do I loop a List of Maps i.e. List<Map<String, Object>> and map the data in my json file?

For e.g. Consider now I've a List<Map<String, Object>> instead of Map<String, Object>

```
public JSONObject response(){
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMap = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> data1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> data2 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> data3 = new HashMap<>();
Context context = new Context();
String responsePayload = null;
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
data1.put("name", "Wayne Rooney")
data1.put("profession", "Footballer")
data2.put("name", "Cristiano Ronaldo")
data2.put("profession", "Footballer")
data3.put("name", "Sir Alex Ferguson")
data3.put("profession", "Manager")
listOfMap.add(data1);
listOfMap.add(data2);
listOfMap.add(data3);
context.setVariable("data", listOfMap);
responsePayload = templateEngine.process("resource/payload", context);
jsonObject = new JSONObject(responsePayload);
return jsonObject;
}
```

So now how do I map this list of data to a JSON file? What changes do I need to make in the JSON file?

I appreciate it if someone helps here.
Thank you!

Comment: Why have a separate map for every entry?  That seems pointless.

Comment: You're not dialing with **files** in any of the snippets you've provided. Did you mean transforming a Collection into a `JSONObject`?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko How do I write the final JSONObject to the payload.json using Thymeleaf

Comment: @accessviolation That's my requirement man